# How can I restrict changing of the keyboard layout to root users only?

Tags: keyboard-layout, root, users, privileges

Is there any way by which I can disable "changing the keyboard layout" so that only a user with root privileges can change the layout.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this ? Are you having a problem or are you trying to set up a kiosk of some kind ?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @EricCarvalho Raised a request to delete. Thanks! I didn't find a solution, but found a fix that is irrelevant to the question but relevant to the bigger picture that I was working on.